# Javascript - Better Alternate to Recursive call

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion, optimization

I have this following problem.
I need to calculate a number x based on time t, x would be represented as M(t).
We have the following

- M(0) = 1
- M(1) = 1
- M(2) = 2
- M(2t) = M(t) + M(t + 1) + t (for t > 1)
- M(2t + 1) = M(t - 1) + M(t) + 1 (for t >= 1)

With that being said the first thing i had in mind to implement this is by using recursion

```
function CalculateForTime(t) {
    if (t == 0 || t == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (t == 2) {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (t % 2 == 0) {
        t = t / 2;
        return CalculateForTime(t) + CalculateForTime(t + 1) + t;
    }
    else {
        t = (t - 1) / 2;
        return CalculateForTime(t - 1) + CalculateForTime(t) + 1;
    }
}
```

This works however it breaks when running on a large number t for example 1^20

I tried looking into tail call recursion or substituting the recursion approach to an iteration approach but couldn't really figure it out.

If tail recursion or iteration is the way to go then please I need help on converting this. If not then I'm open to different methods on making this more optimized.

Thank you,
Omar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a hash table, because for an array it would generate holes with no value.

```js
function calculateForTime(t) {
    var k = t;
    if (k in lookup) {
        return lookup[k];
    }
    if (t == 0 || t == 1) {
        return lookup[k] = 1;
    }
    if (t == 2) {
        return lookup[k] = 2;
    }
    if (t % 2 == 0) {
        t = t / 2;
        return lookup[k] = calculateForTime(t) + calculateForTime(t + 1) + t;
    }
    t = (t - 1) / 2;
    return lookup[k] = calculateForTime(t - 1) + calculateForTime(t) + 1;
}

var lookup = {};
console.log(calculateForTime(1e10));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: After doing like this, the OP should look into a memoizing decorator to hide the details of the caching from the algorithm https://addyosmani.com/blog/faster-javascript-memoization/

Answer (score 0):

You could store the values in an array,then theres no need to recalc...

```js
var times=[1,1,2];
function CalculateForTime(t) {
    t = Math.floor(t / 2);
        return times[t]||(times[t]=CalculateForTime(t) + CalculateForTime(t + 1) + t);
}

console.log(
CalculateForTime(100),
CalculateForTime(1000),
CalculateForTime(10000),
);
console.log(times.slice(0,100));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use memoization to avoid recalculating the same values again and again. See https://addyosmani.com/blog/faster-javascript-memoization/

This is the same as what others suggested, except that it separates the algorithm from the caching of values.

```
function memoize(func){ 
    var cache = {}; 
    return function( arg ){ 
         if(arg in cache) {
             return cache[arg]; 
         } else { 
             return cache[arg] = func( arg );
         } 
     }
  }

  // Overwrite with a function that remember previous results
  CalculateForTime = memoize(CalculateForTime);
```

Pardon any typos, answered from phone